# Python MongoEngine parse JSON-ified DateTimeField as returned from database

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a DateTimeField defined in a model class using MongoEngine:

```
class A(Document):
    ...
    time_m = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    ...
```

When I make a query returning a JSON-ified document of type A, I can see the time represented as:

```
{
  ...
  "time_m": {
              "$date": 1591608726198
            }
  ...
}
```

I want to convert the string '1591608726198' into a human-readable string representation of that date and time using Python but **without using any MongoEngine related classes** (more precisely, I want to convert it in a Jinja2 template).

I have tried the following:

- `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int('1591608726198'))` => `ValueError: year 52406 is out of range`
- `dateutil.parser.parse('1591608726198')` => `OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum`

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and got the answer:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> ts = 1591608726198
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts/1000)
>>> print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
2020-06-08 15:02:06
```

Your timestamp is 13 digit (millisecond precise) and to parse with millisecond precise timestamp, you have to divide by 1000.

Comment: I'm happy to help!